# How to get timezone without moment-timezone.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this string "Mon Oct 21 2013 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)" and I need to convert it to the timezone (GMT-0300) using just moment.js (not moment-timezone.js)

I'm doing this but it's returning the same hour.

```
var startDateTime = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z'),
startMoment = moment.parseZone(startDateTime).zone();
console.log(moment(startDateTime).zone(startMoment).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a moment object with timezone A to timezone B, you can do the following:

```
var startDateTime = "Mon Oct 21 2013 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)";
var newDateTime = moment(startDateTime).zone('-0400').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

Also note that in your example, the initial time `"Mon Oct 21 2013 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"` is already GMT-0300.

Comment: Thanks ! the problem was the GMT-0300